# JSP request object has no parameters

Tags: java, jsp, extjs

I have a JSP file, create.jsp, which receives a POST request from an Ext grid containing a data parameter. Firebug displays a POST like this:

```
{"data":{"a":"","b":"","c":""}}
```

When I try to retrieve the data from the request object in create.jsp using this method,

```
request.getParameter("data");
```

it returns null. In fact the request object contains no parameters or attributes.

I've tested create.jsp with a POST that contains xaction:read and then the request.getParameter("xaction") returns "read", as expected.

Comment: hm, what is the enctype of the submission? Does it happen to be multipart/form-data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a JSON string. Is it really been sent as request **parameter**? I.e.

```
data={"data":{"a":"","b":"","c":""}}
```

Those things are usually sent "plain vanilla" as request **body** which you need to process by `HttpServletRequest#getInputStream()` or `HttpServletRequest#getReader()`.

**Update**: sorry, didn't see that you already figured it out. I had this topic apparently open for too long in a browser tab. But indeed, you need to parse the request body yourself whenever the request is not been sent by a "normal" HTML form. Please keep the character encodings in mind else you will go in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `data` has more than one value, so try:

```
request.getParameterValues("data");
```

Comment: That unfortunately returns `null`.

Comment: loop through request.getParameterNames to see what is coming

Comment: request.getParameterNames was empty.

Comment: 'data' is in the http body, not passed as a request parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using the request.getReader() method to parse the request manually.

Comment: no, if the request is formed properly as a POST request (and not multipart, for example), then getParameter should be OK